Flutter Firestore add collection is only adding to local cache and not to the Firestore in google cloud
I am relatively new to Firebase and today I was trying to utilize Firestore to store user feedback from the app as a collection. Here is the code:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final feedbackProvider = Provider<FeedbackService>((ref) {
  return FeedbackService();
});

class FeedbackService {
  Future<void> submitFeedback(String name, String feedback) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('feedback').add({
        'name': name,
        'feedback': feedback,
        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error submitting feedback: $e");
    }
  }
}


The problem here is FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('feedback').add seems to be only adding to the local cache and the data is not getting synced with Firestore in google cloud. In the same app I use Firebase storage to serve some images, that seems to work fine, so atleast it's not an issue with the app linking to the Firebase project. Please suggest what might be happening here? and if I need to verify something. Thanks!

Are you getting any errors?

What is FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ? , check this value are not null. May be thraw exception  here. Also check your firebase configuration database path.

@AlexMamo no errors it just awaits and the lines after that doesn’t run.  i did a get on that collection and i can see the data but not in cloud.

@DipakPrajapati that just gives current time and it’s not null. I didn’t explicitly provide the database path in my firebase config, i just have all my project details there, let me check what kind of db config i can provide and try. thanks!
